# Webservices with two different context roots in one EAR - JBoss 6.1

Tags: java, web-services, jboss, java-ee-6, jboss6.x

Is it possible to deploy two webservices with different context roots? Each webservice is located in war. Wars and other libs are packed to ear. I'm trying something like that:

```
                <modules>
                    <webModule>
                        <groupId>group</groupId>
                        <artifactId>war1</artifactId>
                        <contextRoot>/api/test</contextRoot>
                    </webModule>
                    <webModule>
                        <groupId>group</groupId>
                        <artifactId>war2</artifactId>
                        <contextRoot>/gateway/test/bs</contextRoot>
                    </webModule>
                </modules>
```

But it doesn't work.

```
java.lang.IllegalStateException: Context root must be the same for all deployed endpoints
```

I'm using JBoss 6.1

Answer (score 0):

You cannot deploy two separate web applications with same context name.

If you want to deploy multiple service end points you don't need to package the applications in separate war files, rather you need to configure multiple endpoints in WEB-INF/...jaxws.xml file. Check the following.

http://www.soa4j.com/RequestContentFromID?q=370576046290944130&lang=en